# unattended-upgrade stuck upgrading kernel

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade, kernel

One of my ubuntu boxes seems to be stuck running unattended-upgrade..and its locking apt so I can't do anything else (also I don't think I should reboot it in this state)

```
root     20027  0.0  0.1 164896 54240 ?        S    Apr05  29:19 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
root     20474  0.0  0.0  20472  4668 pts/0    Ss+  Apr05   0:00 /usr/bin/dpkg --status-fd 10 --configure linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic:amd64 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic:amd64 linux-image-generic:amd64 linux-headers-4.4.0-72:all linux-headers-4.4.0-72-generic:amd64 linux-headers-generic:amd64 linux-generic:amd64 linux-libc-dev:amd64
root     20475  0.0  0.0  24704  6140 pts/0    S+   Apr05   0:00 /usr/bin/perl /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic.postinst configure
root     20484  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Apr02   0:00 [kworker/4:1H]
root     20518  0.0  0.0   4368   644 pts/0    S+   Apr05   0:00 run-parts --verbose --exit-on-error --arg=4.4.0-72-generic --arg=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-72-generic /etc/kernel/postinst.d
root     20569  0.0  0.0   4508   788 pts/0    S+   Apr05   0:00 /bin/sh -e /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-72-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-72-generic
root     20571  0.0  0.0   4508  1640 pts/0    S+   Apr05   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/sbin/update-initramfs -c -t -k 4.4.0-72-generic -b /boot
```

Does anyone know any way I can fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Run `uname -r` to find out what version of the kernel your system is currently running. If it's not 4.4.0-72-generic, it should be safe to reboot. Just be aware that you probably won't be able to boot into 4.4.0-72-generic. Upon reboot, manually run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and see if it hangs again.